# Constraints Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

Как сделать констрейнт отступ слева, который будет являться процентом от всей ширины ? Я понимаю что нужно использовать множитель, но все равно выходит не то что нужно. Пример на скрине. Нужно чтобы отступ лейбла слева, был равен 20% от всей ширины, на всех устройствах.
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно перед лейблом вставить пустое вью и указать для него пропорциональную ширину к общей ширине с коэффициентом 0.2

Comment: идея интересная, но в таком случае в 4 раза увеличивается количество позиционируемых элементов и констрейнтов соответственно. В которых запутаться я думаю будет не сложно.

Comment: @АнтонБушманов тогда остается вариант программного расчета - делаете outlet для leading constraint лейбла и рассчитываете в коде